# Problems modeling logical

Tags: puzzle

I am having problems solving the following logical problem:

In a competition, 5 athletes meet to determine the champion, including A, B, C, D, E. In order to distinguish the winning or losing, they play each pair in an unlimited time. The champion is the one who has the most wins. A couldn't beat C, but A beat B. Because of the extra effort in each match, C won only the first 2 matches. D only won C. B could not win E, but won C and D. E alone lost in only one match. Please tell me who was defeated by E?

I hope to receive help  .Thanks for everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is no tie. Then C beat A, lost to D, lost to B. C won two matches, so C won against E. This is the only match E lost in, so A, B and D were defeated by E.